# Does gaining levels accelerate?

Tags: character-advancement, character-levels, pathfinder-2e

In Pathfinder 2e, an adventurer goes up a level by earning 1000 XP.

If it always takes 1000 XP and adventurers are facing greater foes (who I presume are for more XP), then does it follow that going up levels takes less time the higher the level?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## XP awards are relative

Sadly, this is not explicitly stated in the text, we only get that:

> the XP earned is based on the level of the challenge the party
> overcame. (Core 507)

But on the next page we can see "Table 10-8:XP Awards", which clearly demonstrates that "level of the challange", above, is meant relatively, with rows like:

> Adversary Level / XP award
>
> Party level - 4 / 10 XP
>
> Party level - 3 / 15 XP

and so on. Thus the rate of advancement is steady, barring other factors.